# Coldfusion Proxy confusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am using a proxy/delegate pattern in a coldfusion component, and am getting unexpected results (from my point of view). Below is my proxy component - its pretty straight forward, I just init the CFC with the actual component I want to delegate to, and then map the named functions from that CFC through to a proxy function (the below is simplified for this example)

I have created a proxy component as follows:

```
component output="false"{

    /** Constructor for proxy - requires an instance of myFusebox **/
    public MyFuseboxProxy function init( Required any myFb ){
        variables.myFusebox = arguments.myFb;
        return this;
    }

    this.do = variables.proxy;
    this.getApplication = variables.proxy;
    this.getApplicationData = variables.proxy;

    private any function proxy(){    
        var local.functionName = getFunctionCalledName();
        var local.function = variables.myFusebox[local.functionName];
        var local.returnVal = local.function( argumentCollection=arguments );

        return local.returnVal;
    }
}
```

From my application I call the following code:

```
    variables.myFusebox = new ab.MyFuseboxProxy( variables.myFusebox );
    variables.myFusebox.getApplicationData().startTime = now();
```

Now, in the above scenario, I would expect my proxy component to map the getApplicationData() function straight through to the original myFusebox component (via my `proxy()` function).

That function in the underlying component is as follows:

```
<cffunction name="getApplicationData" returntype="struct" access="public" output="false"
            hint="I am a convenience method to return a reference to the application data cache.">
    <cfreturn getApplication().getApplicationData() />
</cffunction>
```

That proxy all works fine, however, once I am in the above function in the original myFusebox I get the following error:

```
Message: Variable GETAPPLICATION is undefined.
StackTrace: coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedVariableException: Variable GETAPPLICATION is undefined.
```

And if I dump "`this`" inside that function, it actually dumps my proxy object.

Can anyone explain this or what I have done wrong? I was expecting that once the function call was inside the underlying object, it would just use its own context from there (my proxy just being a pass through really to the delegate)

Comment: Is getApplication a function or an object?  If the former, it doesn't have methods.  If the latter, you shouldn't have brackets after it.

Comment: @DanBracuk getApplication() is a function on the target object I am trying to proxy (it returns an object, which has the method getApplicationData() on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the key point:

> I was expecting that once the function call was inside the underlying
>   object

You've got this:

```
private any function proxy(){    
    var local.functionName = getFunctionCalledName();
    var local.function = variables.myFusebox[local.functionName];
    var local.returnVal = local.function( argumentCollection=arguments );

    return local.returnVal;
}
```

When you do this bit:

```
var local.function = variables.myFusebox[local.functionName];
```

you are effectively pulling the function referenced by `local.functionName` *out* of `variables.myFusebox`, and putting it into the current function, within the context of your  `MyFuseboxProxy` instance.

So when you do this:

```
var local.returnVal = local.function( argumentCollection=arguments );
```

You are not running `variables.myFusebox[local.functionName]()` (so in the context of `variables.myFusebox`), but you are running `local.function()` (so in the context of your proxy object).

I don't have the patience to try to follow your logic here, but I am still surprised you get that error. I would have expected this to happen:

1. `local.function` (a reference to `getApplicationData` from `variables.myFusebox`) runs `getApplication()`.
2. `getApplication()` in the context of the `MyFuseboxProxy` instance should be a reference to `variables.proxy()`.
3. `variables.proxy()` resolves the proxied function as `getApplication()`, and pulls that out of `variables.myFusebox`, and runs it in the context of your `MyFuseboxProxy` instance.
4. You do not include the code of the `getApplication()` function from `variables.myFusebox`, so I dunno what would happen next, but this is not what you want to be happening.

Anyway, the crux is - I think - that instead of running the functions inside `variables.myFusebox`, you're running them in your `MyFuseboxProxy` instance instead. If you want to do this sort of proxying (and ignoring for a moment you have `invoke()` specifically for doing this), you need to still call the function in its original context, not reference it in some new context.

I guess you're doing all this horsing around because ColdFusion doesn't like this syntax:

```
someObject[someMethodName]()
```

It baulks at the `[]()` notation. However the solution is not this:

someOutOfContextReference = someObject[someMethodName]
   result = someOutOfContextReference()

It's this:

someObject.someInContextReference = someObject[someMethodName]
   result = someObject.someInContextReference()

See the subtle difference?

ColdFusion functions are not intrinsically closures, which is what you'd need them to be to work the way you want.

Comment: Oh, and - other than to hurt everyone's head - *why* are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking it was probably doing something like this (as with further debugging, I dumped "this" in the target method call and it dumped my proxy class).  I was using this approach rather than invoke as I didn't realise cfinvoke was now available in cfscript (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html obviously isn't the complete list).

Comment: The reason for the proxy/delegate pattern is that I wanted to intercept all calls to a couple of methods in the underlying object (myFusebox is a component of the Fusebox framework so didnt want to start modifying their source code to do this) - Are there any easier ways to intercept all calls to a method on another component than my proxy approach?

Comment: Oh, and yes - I switched to invoke() and it made life much simpler and worked! so accepting the answer.

Comment: I'd probably extend the original CFC with overriden functions. However perhaps not possible depending on how you need to invoke Fusebox. Given Fusebox is dead though, I would question whether it's actually OK to just go fix/change whatever it is you need to address. What's the risk, really?

Comment: Yeah, my original plan was to extend the component, but having looked at it, I would have still had to then go change the fusebox source as it seemed to be doing a lot of initialisation cruft, so wouldn't have been as simple as just instantiating my extended component in my app.  You're right though if there is no longer devwork on fusebox I might as well just change whatever.